# Exclude an exit code in github actions workflow result status

Tags: python-3.x, github, github-actions

I have a workflow which in one of its steps, if the command finishes with exit code 1 (failure), I want to run the next command/job (fix the problem which caused previous command failure), but I don't want that exit code 1 to affect the workflow result status.
In this situation, if I have exit code 1, even if I fix the problem, the result status will be `failure`, but I want the result status to be `success` if the second command fixed the problem.
Is this possible?

Here is my `workflow.yml`:
\

```
name: autoblack
on: [pull_request, push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set up Python 3.8
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2.2.2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
      - name: Install Black
        run: pip3 install git+git://github.com/psf/black
        
      - name: Run black --check .
        run: black --check .
  
  reformat:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [build]
    if: always() && (needs.build.result == 'failure')
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4
      - name: Set up Python 3.8
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2.2.2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
      - name: Install Black
        run: pip3 install git+git://github.com/psf/black
      - name: If needed, commit black changes to the pull request
        env:
          NEEDS_CONTEXT: ${{ toJSON(needs) }}
        run: |
          black --fast .
          git config --global user.name 'autoblack'
          git config --global user.email 'signorrayan@users.noreply.github.com'
          git remote set-url origin https://x-access-token:${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}@github.com/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY
          git checkout $GITHUB_HEAD_REF
          echo "$NEEDS_CONTEXT"
          git commit -am "fixup: Format Python code with Black"
          git push
          echo "$NEEDS_CONTEXT"
```

If the job `build` with command `run: black --check .` has exit code 1, I want to run the job `reformat` to fix the problem and push that to the repository. The second job works fine, but the final result label is failure!!

Comment: Did you try using `black --check || true` ? The `|| true` suffix will ignore the command output error (always consider it as true) and allow to continue the workflow job or steps without returning failure. That way, you can eventually use `black --check &> output.txt || true` to create an output file and check in another step if this output file contains `exit code 1` or not (for example, with `grep -q`) and save it as failure in a job output variable, to use in the second job `if` condition.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me with an semi-related problem; we have a command that succeeds, but always returns 1. The || true fixed THAT problem! Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`continue-on-error`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepscontinue-on-error) attribute of the `step` (also available [on the job](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontinue-on-error)) can be used to prevent a job from failing when a step fails.

Then the `steps` context contains a `steps.<step_id>.outcome` that can be used in expressions to determine if the prior step failed. For example, in the workflow below I have a step that will fail when the commitlint command fails, but it uses continue-on-error to allow the workflow to continue:

```yaml
      - name: commitlint
        id: commitlint
        continue-on-error: true
        run: |
          npx commitlint --from ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.sha }} --to ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }} --verbose
```

Then the subsequent two steps will apply or remove a label based on the commitlint step's success/failure outcome:

```yaml
      - name: label when commitlint fails
        if: ${{ steps.commitlint.outcome == 'failure' }}
        uses: andymckay/labeler@1.0.4
        with:
          add-labels: "commit-message-rule-violation"

      - name: label removal when commitlint succeeds
        if: ${{ steps.commitlint.outcome == 'success' }}
        uses: andymckay/labeler@1.0.4
        with:
          remove-labels: "commit-message-rule-violation"
```

The workflow ultimately succeeds regardless of whether the commitlint step fails or not due to `continue-on-error: true`.

The complete working workflow for this is [here](https://github.com/activescott/files-and-folders/blob/4d31ac1daaeafd94c3319f316e4f0761f8b20b76/.github/workflows/commitlint.yml)

Answer (score 0):

As an example, you can use an if condition to [set the output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter) and refer to it in subsequent steps

```
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Install Black
        run: pip3 install git+git://github.com/psf/black
      - name: Check black status
        id: black_status
        run: |
          if black --check .; then
            echo "::set-output name=result::true"
          else
            echo "::set-output name=result::false"
          fi
      - if: steps.black_status.outputs.result == 'true'
        name: Check1
        run: echo "hi"
      - if: steps.black_status.outputs.result == 'false'
        name: Check2
        run: echo "yo"
```

Comment: That'll will allow the steps to run based on the result, but the problem I've run into is the same as the OP - the overall workflow will show as "failed" even though you planned for this failure and worked around it in the steps.

So that's really the question - how do you allow a job or step to fail, but mark the overall workflow as successful?